# Deriving the area of a trapezoid by converting it into a rectangle

Tags: geometry, area

I am learning geometry and was trying to discover myself area of a trapezoid.
I know the area of rectangle is `A = width * length`. I learned in school how we can split a parallelogram and convert it to rectangle and thus the `area of parallelogram` = `area of a rectangle`.

Similarly I was trying to convert a trapezoid to a rectangle. Seen in below image. So shouldn't the `area of trapezoid` also be `area of a rectangle`.

[image]

Comment: Could you label the new rectangle?

Comment: That only works if you start with an *isosceles* trapezoid, otherwise the left triangle won't fit on the right. Instead, draw the median and look for some *other* triangles you could flip.

Comment: Yes correct i just drew a non-iscosceles trapezoid and i tried to convert it to a rectangle, but it cannot. Thus the area of trapezoid != the area of a rectangle. Thanks.

Comment: @geouser Yes it works, just with a different construction. See the "trapezoid" section [here](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/geometry/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-parallelogram-kite-or-trapezoid/) for example.

Comment: Yes correct, basically finding the median and reconstructing it to a rectangle! Great thanks.

Comment: So the area of a trapezoid would be = ((width1+width2)/2) * height

Comment: I suggest instead, taking two copies of your trapezium, and building a parallelogram from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the figure below, your trapezoid is $ABCD$, which is clearly not isosceles.  $EF$ is midway between $AD$ and $BC$.  Now $AEH$ will fill in the corner at the top left and $DFG$ will fill in the corner at the top left.  We now have a rectangle with height the height of the trapezoid and base that is the average of the two bases of the trapezoid, giving the traditional formula $$area=height*\frac 12(base_1 +base_2)$$
[image]